# Sending a variable of a query to an input from a php function

Tags: php, javascript, variables, input

I have this autocomplete php function:

search.php

```
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('inb');

$rs = mysql_query('select name, l_name, level from pacient 
            where name like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"
            or l_name like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"
            order by name asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $nivel = $row['nivel_nivel'];
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['name'].' '. $row['l_name'].' '.$row['level'],
            'value' => $row['name'].' '. $row['l_name'].' '.$row['level']
        );
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Which I call it to the html main file with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#nameField').autocomplete({source:'search.php', minLength:1});
        });
```

Now, I want to get a value of the query made in the php file, and place it in a input field of the html file. Any idea how can I make this?

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). And in your query you don't escape `%` and `_`, use [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/addcslashes) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a listener to the [`response`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) method in your JS autocomplete definition. You would need to change your PHP to include the new value you want somewhere in that dataset.

Something like this:

```
$data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['name'].' '. $row['l_name'].' '.$row['level'],
        'value' => $row['name'].' '. $row['l_name'].' '.$row['level'],
        'foo' => <WHATEVER VALUE YOU WANT HERE>
    );
```

and then in the jQuery:

```
$('#nameField').autocomplete({
    source:'search.php', 
    minLength:1,
    response : function(event, data) {
        data.content[0].foo; //this will have your foo value, do whatever you want with it here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!, just one doubt.. In there, how can I assign it to an input field?

Comment: `$('input.whatever').val(data.content[0].foo)` - something along those lines